# Web based tool: 2D board to indicate client status

Tags: project-management, whiteboard

I've been using a whiteboard to visualize client relation status.

```
________________Good______________
|                |               |
|                |               |
|                |               |
|Cost____________|_______________|Revenue
|                |               |
|                |               |
|                |               |
|________________|_______________|
                Bad
```

Then we've been using logos of the customer + magnets to move them around the board.

This is an elegant way to visualize the client status. The upper right is the sweet spot where you would like all clients to be, and clients the lower left is those where you should end your relation.

Now we're a distributed team, so we need some web based tool to do this.

One could do it with an ordinary online drawing tool, for example https://sketch.io/sketchpad/, but it's not convenient to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could reproduce a very similar layout to your whiteboard using a shared spreadsheet. For that, you could use a shared document in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/). It's more elegant than a drawing program because of the grid format, and anyone with permission could add or move a name. You could also use color coding, or keep using the logos by inserting them as images.

Here is an example:

[image]

---

**Edit:**

You could also use a document with a table instead of the spreadsheet. Same principles apply with the advantage that you could directly insert an image within a cell in the table

Comment: Yes, thats actually a good idea. A little bit clumpy, but is good enough. Let's see if someone finds an even better solution.

Comment: @Jonas I agree. Welcome to StackExchange, by the way. It's also common practice on SE to wait for a day or a few before accepting an answer. Better ones might be posted